# Newtonsoft.Json Error: 'Can not convert array to string'

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I am using newtonsoft to serialize and deserialize objects. I am using the following bit of code to read a string from the posted values:

```
string className;
JToken classToken;
jsonData.TryGetValue("Class", out classToken);
className= (string)classToken;
```

This works fine. Suppose the following is the JSON that is being posted, how can I read the "Students" array with the above method?

```
"Students": ["1", "3"],
"Class": "Fifth"
```

I tried the following code but it gives error 'Can not convert array to string'

```
string[] StudentsName;
JToken StudentsToken;
jsonData.TryGetValue("Students", out StudentsToken);
StudentsName= (string)StudentsToken;//How to assign this to an array?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the string to the First Index of the array

```
string[] StudentsName = new string[5];
JToken StudentsToken;
jsonData.TryGetValue("Students", out StudentsToken);
StudentsName[0] =  StudentsToken.ToString();
```

Comment: Same error with StudentsName[0] = (string)StudentsToken; StudentsToken does not have a method .ToCharArray()

Comment: @user1640256 did you try the above?

Comment: Yes. This time the error says: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: ok then you have to inialize the array , check the modified answer

Comment: Not exactly but string[] StudentsName = new string[1] did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `StudentsToken.ToString()` will give you `["1", "3"]`.